# How to put new sequence in a Sortable Table wtih <input> field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I put this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/thhd7k11/12/) together to help explain better what I need.

I created a similar table of all the work orders we have in our system.  I created a form to be able to sort the working sequence (the priority).  I added the Sortable plugin and I can drag and drop everything into place.

However, I cannot figure out how to put the new sequence into the INPUT field I call "sequence"

In the example of the Avtex Blog by Steven Ray I can get everything done that I need, except change this line:

```
//Renumber table rows
function renumber_table(tableID) {
    $(tableID + " tr").each(function() {
        count = $(this).parent().children().index($(this)) + 1;
        //alert(count);

        //$(this).find('.priority').html(count);  <--- Original Line

    //////  This is where I'm trying to select the INPUT field, 
    //////  and place the value of count into it.  Obviously this is not 
    //////  working, but I cannot figure out the correct line.

        $(this).find('.priority').("input").val(count);
});
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help curing my ignorance.

JP in KC

Comment: Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/thhd7k11/12/

Comment: My apologies, I cannot see the change, or the change does not update the input field on the JSFiddle you reference.

Comment: In your fiddle, the drag on the table rows does not works :)

Comment: Thank you for fixing it!!!  Any idea how to change the selector so I can update the content of the INPUT field?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hackerman for making the JSFiddle work!

The answer to my question is:

```
$(this).find('.priority :input').val(count);
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pampas/thhd7k11/14/) has been updated to show how it works.

My thanks to Hackerman for providing the tool for me to solve my own problem.

Thanks
JP in KC